# how actions must be in redux-thunk axios async?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, redux-thunk, dispatch

Good afternoon

I am a newbie. Want to make a CRUD using reacts,redux-thunk, axios, json-server.

but I've found hard to stick in one correct way to deal with actions

I have this reducer:

```
import { types } from "../types/types";

const initialState = {
    data: null,
    deleted: null,
    error: ''
}

export const axiosDataReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.get:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.data
            }
        case types.delete:
            return {
                ...state,
                deleted: action.deletedItem
            }

        case types.error:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.msg
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I have this actions:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { baseURL } from "../json-server/baseURL"
import { types } from '../types/types'


// get data
export const fetchData = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.get(baseURL)
            .then(response => {
                return response.data
            })
            .then(data => {
                dispatch({
                    type: types.get,
                    data: data
                })
            })
            .catch(error => dispatch(
                {
                    type: types.error,
                    msg: "Unable to fetch data"
                }));
    };
};
//delete data
export const deleteData = (id) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.get(`${baseURL}${id}`)
            .then(response => {
                return response.data
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                dispatch({
                    type: types.error,
                    deletedItem: data
                })
            })
            .catch(error => dispatch(
                {
                    type: types.error,
                    msg: "Unable to delete data"
                }));

    };
};
```

I have this (Table component) component in which I use a dispatch inside a useEffect and works, I get the data and I render the data inside my table, but I don t know why is working like that, isn t a double dispatch inside the useEffect?:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchData } from '../actions/actions';
import ButtonCreate from './buttons/ButtonCreate';
import ButtonDelete from './buttons/ButtonDelete';
import ButtonUpdate from './buttons/ButtonUpdate';

export default function Tabla() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { data } = useSelector(state => state.axiosDataReducer)

    useEffect(() => {

        dispatch(fetchData())


    }, [])


    return (
        <div className='container mt-5 mb-5'>
            <ButtonCreate />
            <table className="table table-striped table-hover caption-top ">
                <caption>Online Store</caption>
                <thead className='table-dark'>
                    <tr className='text-center'>
                        <th scope="col">Id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Cost</th>
                        <th scope="col">Category</th>
                        <th scope="col">Department</th>
                        <th scope="col">Update</th>
                        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        data?.map((x, index) => (
                            <tr key={x.id}>
                                <th scope="col">{index + 1}</th>
                                <th scope="col">{x.name}</th>
                                <th scope="col">$ {x.cost.toFixed(2)}</th>
                                <th className='text-center'>
                                    {
                                        x.category.map((y, index) => (
                                            <span key={index * 0.125}>{y.name}</span>
                                        ))
                                    }
                                </th>
                                <th className='text-center'>
                                    {
                                        x.department.map((z, index) => (
                                            <span key={index * 0.225}>{z.name}</span>
                                        ))
                                    }
                                </th>
                                <th><ButtonUpdate /></th>
                                <th><ButtonDelete id={x.id} /></th>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    )
}
```

and in the same Table component, I want to click the delete button:

```
import React from 'react'
import { deleteData } from '../../actions/actions'

export default function ButtonDelete({ id }) {

    return (
        <div>
            <button
                className='btn btn-danger'
                onClick={deleteData(id)}
            >
                Delete
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

, but now, for this previous example, it just will dispatch the element I am pointing to, the console.log works fine, but if I try to dispatch I obtain this error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): dispatch is not a function

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dispatch is not a function
```

What does this means?

I want to find out the most basic way of doing this asyc request to server using actions. I don t know why is dispatching not working properly.

thanks in advance, I apreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `deleteData()` function . I believe you should use `types.delete` in your dispatch type instead of `types.error`.

Also, in your `Table` component, you must use `useDispatch` as well. Because, this hook returns a reference to the `dispatch` function from the Redux store that must be passed to `deleteData`. And your `onClick` event should have a function that returns a dispatch. Something like this maybe:

```
<button
   className='btn btn-danger'
   onClick={() => dispatch(deleteData(id))}
>
```

You might want to check [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch) as well.

Comment: your answer is correct. I've used ```<button
   className='btn btn-danger'
   onClick={dispatch(deleteData(id)}
>``` causing an explosion in the code..however, what about the double dispatch in useEffecct...? its a big bad thing or a newbie-could-be-accepted-piece-of-code?

Comment: If you are referring to `dispatch(fetchData())`, it is not a double dispatch. `useEffect` returns a `dispatch`. If you like [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/hooks/useDispatch.ts#L16) you could see that `dispatch` is a reference to `store.dispatch`.  This function actually changes the store, based on the action type and data you provided. And in your `fetchData` action creator you are simply passing this `dispatch` inside  `.then()` method to execute `store.dispatch` with an object `{ type: types.get, data: data  }`